# How to implement "IdP first" scenario for WS-Federation

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, saml, adfs2.0, ws-federation

ADFS 2.0, WIF (WS-Federation): I want to implement SSO in the scenario when user goes to IdP web-site first to be authenticated. In this scenario our customers have intranet web-portals with links to our (service provider) web site, which actually lead them to IdP web site and redirect them to our web site as soon as user is authenticated. I could not find any info with technical details on how to implement it properly, can anybody?

What I did so far, I grabbed the redirection link to IdP using Fiddler to use as portal link and looks like it works, however I'm not sure if it's a proper way to do that. If you have similar experience please share.

UPDATE: More detailed use case: Our customer has its own intranet portal with link to our web site (service provider). The idea is to avoid additional initial http redirections and to have single entry point for different customers, so that our web site can count on security token coming from user to recognize identity of the customer, in other case we should have separate uri for any customer. User clicks the link, it leads him first to its own intranet IdP service (ADFS 2.0) that authenticates him with his windows account and adds security token and redirects him to our (relying party) web site where we can recognize him and his organization (customer) by the token, and he can consume our services. Let me know if something wrong or seems suspicious with the scenario.

Comment: Can you provide more detail in a use case? e.g. customer logs into app., customer is redirected by WIF to ... Document the actual behaviour and then the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Normal case is that the RP URL bound to ADFS via FedUtil is what ADFS return to. So if the portal is bound to ADFS (doesn't sound like it because you don't have to log in to get there?) then that's where you return when authenticated.

If your web site is what's bound to ADFS, then user goes to portal, clicks on link, gets authenticated, token with claims created and redirect to your web site.

Comment: Right, second scenario. I wonder if there is any online sample that demonstrates the second scenario so that I do not have to make it up. For example, the first question brought up is how our customer URL to IdP (ADFS) should look like.